# NSDate after format return 47130101?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

The code is like :

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter;
formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];

for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {

    dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(aQueue, ^{
    NSString *dateKey = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];


        NSLog(dateKey);


    });

}
```

Is datekey sometimes be 47130101 ?
The normal value is  like 20120608.
But I get 47130101 sometimes.

Comment: what do you mean by sometimes ? what is the context of this usage ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly valid, I tried it some times to check and it's valid.

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", dateKey);
```

And you will see it. Probably you are getting confuse in other part.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", dateKey); Does not change anything, I try it, it is the same result , I can't get 47130101 .

Comment: It doesn't change anything what it shows you that the variable is always correct, really, your code its ok, look for the error in other part.

Comment: I understand what you say, in the example code ,the result is always correct , but in my Application ,it return wrong result sometimes ,in my Application I use  dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(aQueue, ^{     to run the code in the asynchronous way,  I think may be  is the problem with it .

Comment: I change the example code , it will be wrong sometimes . I think NSDateFormatter  is not Thread safe is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely do not want to use the same `NSDateFormatter` object on multiple threads simultaneously.

[Thread Safety](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html) does indicate that NSDateFormatter is explicitly thread-unsafe.

I would suggest that if you are going to do this in GCD anyway that you either use multiple NSDateFormatters (possibly a pool if you really need to do 10,000 of these), or single-thread the access if your main concern is "accidentally" using it in multiple threads.

If you choose the latter, I'd create a dedicated serial dispatch queue for the NSDateFormatter and use that to control access so that it'll only run on one thread at a time, but otherwise will execute quickly if it's unlikely that you'll get a collision.

Answer (score -4):

```
  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
  NSString *dateKey = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: whats the difference from yyyyMMdd ?

Comment: yes it's the same, i just pasted a code from a project( i removed the "-")